# Cron sync mysql tables

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a remote server that needs to access my mysql database a lot. So I figured instead of sending a bunch of remote mysql commands it would be more effecient to sync the database to the remote server. Is there a program that easily does this and that I can configure to only sync specified tables and possibly columns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mysql offers [replication,](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) which should do the trick.

Comment: Is there a nice frontend for configuring it?

Comment: yes - vi is very nice and runs on nearly every operating system (you didn't say which you are using)